# XPath Search troubles

Tags: xml, xpath

I can't seem to grab this specific node.

```
<w:body>
    <w:p wsp:rsidR="00D12EE7" wsp:rsidRDefault="00F86B09">
      <w:fldSimple w:instr=" MERGEFIELD GAS_REAFCity ">
         <w:r>
           <w:rPr>
             <w:noProof/>
           </w:rPr>
           <w:t>«GAS_REAFCity»</w:t>
         </w:r>
       </w:fldSimple>
    </w:p>
</w:body>
```

I have tried can get as close as //w:p/w:fldSimple
but how do i select  w:instr=" MERGEFIELD GAS_REAFCity ".

Thanks
Appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't attributes use the @ syntax, so you'd select @w:instr ?

```
//w:p/w:fldSimple[@w:instr=" MERGEFIELD GAS_REAFCity "]
```

[XPath Expression Tester](http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm)

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath will grab the element node, but you want the attribute node. Your xpath will need to be something like `//w:p/w:fldSimple/@w:instr`. depending on what your using to evaluate the xpath you could probably use something like myAttr.getText(), alternatively, you can use `string(//w:p/w:fldSimple/@w:instr)`.

I notice that your XPath is relative, is this intentional? Lastly, there are many excellent frameworks for processing DOMs and XPaths, and I know at least Dom4J will allow you to programmatically walk a Dom tree and then you can query the XPath that would access that node.

I found the following [tutorial](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html) useful when starting out

Hope this helps